# For any two positive numbers, $p$ and $q$, which is larger $p^q$ or $q^p$?

Tags: calculus, inequality

For $p>0$ and $q>0$, which is larger $p^q$ or $q^p$? Give a complete analysis of the function $f(p,q)=p^q-q^p$, for $p>0$ and $q>0$. You may need to make bounds on your values of $p$ and $q$. You will want to give a comprehensive "picture" of when the function is positive, negative, and most particularly when it is zero.

What I have so far:

Consider the determination of whether $p^q > q^p$. By division, I get:

$\frac{p^q}{q^p}=\frac{e^{p \ln p}}{e^{p \ln q}}=e^{q \ln p - p \ln q}>1$

I know that $e^x>1$ if $x>0$, so I need to determine when $q \ln p - p \ln q >0$.

How can I convert this to an analysis of the function $f(x)=\frac{x}{\ln x}$ and use calculus to help solve the problem?

Comment: Hint: study the function $x^{1/x}$, in particular its critical point for positive $x$.

Comment: @graydad - I have edited my original question. I realized that I forgot to add that I am looking at $p^q > q^p$.

Comment: @Macavity - doesn't $x^{1/x}$ have a global maximum at $x=e$?

Comment: @Macavity - I have that if $p=q$, then $p^q=q^p$ (obviously). I also have that if $p,q<e$, then if $p>q, p^q > q^p$ and if $p,q>e$, then if $p<q, p^q > q^p$. Am I on the right track there? I am still trying to work through when they are on opposite sides of $e$.

Comment: Right so far. The last case is where things are not so simple.